# Wildcard DNS, two solutions, which one?

Tags: domain-name-system, zones

Hy,
I got a domain (say example.com) and a server (say IP 1.2.3.4). I want to relay every traffic which is requested from the domain to my server. Every subdomain should be handled like this (so wildcard DNS). There should be one exception: The subdomain `mail.example.com` should be routed to another ip (say IP 2.3.4.5)

My previous hoster made the following zone-file for the dns server for me:

```
@                        IN A       1.2.3.4
mail                     IN A       2.3.4.5
*                        IN CNAME   @
```

Now, my new DNS-Hoster claims this is invalid and proposes this new zone file to me:

```
@                        IN A       1.2.3.4
mail                     IN A       2.3.4.5
*                        IN A       1.2.3.4
```

**Is the first one realy wrong? Is the second one correct and does what I want?**

I already read [I a Wildcard CName DNS Record Valid](https://serverfault.com/questions/44618/is-a-wildcard-cname-dns-record-valid), so the first one should not be wrong but only unsuported.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Read the full explanation here: [Is a wildcard CNAME DNS record valid?](https://serverfault.com/questions/44618/is-a-wildcard-cname-dns-record-valid)

Is not wrong, but some providers doesn't support it.

Yes the second is correct and have the same efect.

Comment: Okay, I already read that. But does the second solution do the same?

Comment: yes have the same effect.