# Wildcard CNAME with GoDaddy DNS Manager

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, godaddy, wildcard, heroku

I'm having some issues with GoDaddy DNS that I thought I'd maybe share with you all before moving to another provider.

I have an application that uses subdomains for users and is hosted on Heroku.com. I want the entire site to be accessed via https but the way Heroku does this is tricky. Typically Heroku gives you 3 IP address that you can create a * record for the wildcard subdomains. This works fine with Godaddy.

My issue is that, with the way Heroku does SSL, is that instead of the IP address, they instead give you an AmazonAws url. So for an example subdomain of "foo", you can create a cname with a host name of foo that looks at your amazonaws.com address. Well users on my site are making subdomains frequently, and so I'd like to use a wildcard CNAME. I've read here that it is a legit practice (though not recommended) but unfortunately I believe I have to if I want the security I desire.

Has anyone been able to create a wildcard cname on GoDaddy? Is anyone else on Heroku in the same situation as me that's found a nice work around, possibly the Zerigo DNS Add-on?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Heroku warn against "naked" domain names?](http://serverfault.com/questions/408017/why-does-heroku-warn-against-naked-domain-names)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a wildcard CNAME DNS record valid?](https://serverfault.com/questions/44618/is-a-wildcard-cname-dns-record-valid)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have been answered previously here [Is a wildcard CNAME DNS record valid?](https://serverfault.com/questions/44618/is-a-wildcard-cname-dns-record-valid)

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Wildcards are now allowed in Godaddy records (at least A records according to [this community support answer](https://www.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Domains/Can-I-add-a-wildcard-A-Record/td-p/127110) and probably CNAMES as well, based on @MemeDeveloper's feedback

**Original Answer (2012):**
I just called Godaddy... twice, and both of them said (the second one very definitively) that there is no way to do a wildcard CNAME in GoDaddy, even if you have Premium DNS.

The post linked to by Flimzy mentions using ** instead of *, which GoDaddy will let you do, but it doesn't function as a wildcard record.

Kinda disappointing.

Comment: This is no longer true. I just put * in as my Host for a CNAME in Godaddy (standard account DNS Manager) and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with GoDaddy DNS. Some issues may come up with GoDaddy shared hosting but you should be able to create a wildcard CNAME in the DNS service.

Comment: What does the record look like I should be creating? * is not allowed for the CNAME host.

Comment: * is now allowed for the CNAME Host in DNS Manager in Godaddy (in 2020)