# Why does Heroku warn against "naked" domain names?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, cloud, cloud-computing, heroku

I ran across [this page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/avoiding-naked-domains-dns-arecords) in the Heroku docs...

> Naked domains, also called bare or apex domains, are configured in DNS via A-records and have serious availability implications when used in highly available environments such as massive on-premise datacenters, cloud infrastructure services, and platforms like Heroku.
>
> For maximum scalability and resiliency applications should avoid naked domains and instead rely solely on subdomain-based hostnames.

Does anyone here speak Enterprise? What are the "availability implications" they're warning about?

(I notice that http://stackoverflow.com works no problem, so evidently there are viable alternate philosophies on this issue.)

Comment: I run [www.yes-www.org](http://www.yes-www.org/) and I approve this question.

Comment: There is another concern, too: static assets can't be served without attached cookies (you can't add cookies JUST for the root domain; cookies must be for a subdomain or for `.domain.com` (wildcard, used if root domain)). You can work around this by serving assets from a different domain (SE uses [sstatic.net](http://sstatic.net)) to avoid the hideous www subdomain.

Comment: @MichaelHampton why can't we leave comments on www.yes-www.org? Why don't you mention `ALIAS` (or `ANAME` records) in your page?

Comment: This question is 6 years old, and mainly about limitations in software.  Any updates?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

What they're talking about is that when you use a `CNAME` to point to their services (which is only possible on subdomain, not the zone root - it can't coexist with the `SOA` and `NS` records that are required on the root of your zone), they can make a change to their own DNS records to work around some kind of availability issue.

With a zone root, you must use an `A` record to point to a specific IP address for the service.  If they have an issue with routing, or some kind of denial of service against that specific address, they're not able to update *your zone's* `A` record to point to a different IP on the fly; they can update their own, though, and that's what a `CNAME` allows them to do.

This doesn't apply to Stack Exchange because they aren't using a third party's platform; they'll be the ones responding to an availability issue, so whether it's a `CNAME` or an `A` makes no difference to them.

Comment: What about `ALIAS` (or `ANAME`) records?

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger Those aren't actually a DNS record type - they're a configuration where certain DNS providers will handle the abstraction of dynamically checking the current `A` record of the target, then serving it back in response to a query for that name.  They're essentially designed to solve this exact problem, so they're definitely appropriate to use for this case.

Comment: So if we use them, the scalability warning from heroku doesn't remain true anymore, right? Or is there any technical drawback into using them?

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger Correct.  The technical drawback is in the implementation difficulty, as a "standard" DNS server cannot accomplish that kind of thing without customization.  As long as your provider's implementation is stable, it should be just as good as a `CNAME` setup on a subdomain.

Answer (score 13):

As an addition to @ShaneMadden's answer, one workaround is for the third-party platform to also manage your DNS zone. For example, if you use AWS's [Elastic Load Balancer](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) service, **and** their [Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53) DNS service, you can reliably point the zone apex at an ELB instance using their custom [alias records](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/#Zone_apex), which allows them to update your DNS zone in response to availability issues.

This is however an argument against the [no-www](http://no-www.org/) concept, since `www.example.com` can have a `CNAME` record.