# Configuring "@" CNAME record in GoDaddy control panel

Tags: domain-name-system, godaddy

I have `mydomain.com` that is hosted on an Azure VM instance called `mymachine.cloudapp.net`

I need to configure DNS so that both `www.mydomain.com` and `mydomain.com` get mapped to the same host. I'm using GoDaddy as registrar.

Currently GoDaddy offers me to create an empty (`@`) A record, so that if I ping `mymachine.cloudapp.net` and resolve its VIP address I can store it in the A record.

Unfortunately, if the VIP changes and I forget to re-ping I get `mydomain.com` unreachable, and that's normal.

When I try to move that `@` record to the CNAME section so it best points to the VM hostname, I get the following error:

```
A record of a different type exists for the hostname @, could not create CNAME
```

This occurs both if I delete the A record and write CNAME, and if there is no `@` record in the A section.

How can one set a `@` CNAME record in a GoDaddy managed domain?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In short, you can't make the @ record a CNAME without deleting all other resource records for @, and you can't do that since some (like the NS records) are required for proper DNS functionality. This is one reason why [providers such as Heroku tell you not to use naked domain names](https://serverfault.com/q/408017/126632).

You will need a host to perform the HTTP redirection from `example.com` to `www.example.com` for you, to which you will point `A` (and `AAAA`) record for @.

If your DNS is hosted with GoDaddy, then they have a free service that will do this for you. In your GoDaddy domain manager, look on the left hand side for "Forwarding" and click "Manage". Then set it to forward `example.com` to `www.example.com` and update your DNS to support the change. You should leave the Advanced Options at their defaults.

[image: GoDaddy Domain Forwarding Control]

Comment: Would Domain Forwarding also effect subdomains? I want to redirect all users to example.org to www.example.org Would enabling domain forwarding do that?

Comment: what if I want to pass arguments in the url? When I forward the url from the naked one that had url args passed in from the original request it strips away the query string of the url and just forwards me to the www. port of my site

Comment: Godaddy forwarding from the bare url doesn't work with deep links anymore. It has a short-link feature that gets in the way.

Comment: GoDaddy forwarding also doesn't work when using HTTPS

Comment: what if I dont want to redirect to www and I want to access  the site directly https://example.com

Answer (score -1):

You can't add a new @ CNAME record without deleting all of the other records in GoDaddy.

Instead leave the CNAME records as they are, and set the A (Apex) Record like mentioned in the docs http://surge.sh/help/adding-a-custom-domain
[image]

It should look like this:

```
; A Records
@   1800    IN  A   45.55.110.124
```

or in the GUI:

```
Type: A
Name: @
Points to: 45.55.110.124
```

Comment: Not sure how this answers the question? The question specified that an A-record was what was currently being done, but it wasn't a good fit for the moving ip address.