# Remove www from domain name in nginx

Tags: nginx

I want to remove `www.` from both the main site and all sublevel domains. I don't care how many levels into the TLD I am; `www` is banned from use. It should issue a 301 redirect.

- www.example.com
- www.123.example.com

I wrote the following server block, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(www\.)(?<domain>.+)$;
    return 301 $scheme://$domain/$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Be careful. You will have [trouble using various cloud services](http://serverfault.com/q/408017/126632) if you do not use www.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do this:

```
server {
   listen       80;
   server_name  ~^www\.(?<domain>.+?)$;
   return 301 $scheme://$domain/$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: um, that is what I'm doing minus the capture group.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: yes sir, it is the same though. Just one more loose `$1` floating around...

Comment: So, what doesn't work exactly?

Answer (score 0):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323735/nginx-remove-www-and-respond-to-both):

```
if ($http_host ~* "^www\.(.+)$"){
rewrite ^(.*)$ http://%1$request_uri redirect;
}
```