# how to get rid of the "www" in the url with AWS EC2 and Route 53 services.

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-route53

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get rid of "www" in the url.

I am looking for giving access to the website when you type down mywebiste.co as well as redirecting www.mywebsite.co to mywebsite.co

I have tried through apache2, in the configuration files and create a virtual host but that didn't work from the tutorial I used.

I'm thinking maybe I have to configure something else with AWS ? I don't really know what to look for to be honest. therefore my post here.

I own the domain name with GoDaddy, and use Route 53 and EC2 on AWS to have my servers set up.

You can try it here : www.meetmyfriends.co

Many thanks.

Comment: You need to be doing it the other way: [redirecting no-www to www](http://serverfault.com/a/576469/126632). Otherwise [you can't use Route 53 or services like it, and will have trouble with other services like Heroku](http://serverfault.com/q/408017/126632).

Comment: Thank you Michael, I appreciate your advice.

How do I redirect no-www to www ? I you look at meetmyfriends.co you will se there is absolutely nothing at this page and I don't know how to address this issue. I'be been trying to set up virtual host on apache without success.
Many Thanks

Comment: The link shows you how to configure Route 53 for it. Setting up the virtual host would be a separate question.

Comment: I want to make sure I understand what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to setup a redirect for www.meetmyfriends.co to meetmyfriends.co or trying to get meetmyfriends.co to point to your web server?  The reason I ask is when I do a DNS lookup for meetmyfriends.co, it does not look like it has an A record configured.  This would cause meetmyfriends.co not to work.

Comment: So I don't know if I'm doing it wrong with the virtual host configuration or if this is something that should be handled with AWS somehow ? Route 53 manages "meetmyfriends.co." which seems to be ok with no-www .. ?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: ok I will give it a try thank you :)

Comment: @imperalix: Thank you for your help, yes, I think you are right, there is something not working with no-www as when following tutorials online for no-www (virtual host or .htaccess) it does not work/gives satisfying results, therefore this post: I think it comes from somewhere else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to create an A record for meetmyfriends.co.  To do this, inside of your zone do the following.

1. Click Create Record Set
2. Leave Name empty
3. Ensure type is set to A
4. In the value section enter **54.214.246.243**
5. Click create.

Comment: Wow that was it, verrry simple thank you so much !