# Set MX records on a CNAME domain (heroku app)

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, cname-record, heroku

I have a heroku app on a subdomain like x.herokuapp.com which is mapped to my domain name via a CNAME record. I want emails to be handled by zohomail so I've tried setting up MX records but these seem to fail.

Am I correct that even emails are mapped through the CNAME instead of the MX record?

```
www.x.com   CNAME   x.herokuapp.com
x.com       CNAME   x.herokuapp.com
x.com       MX      mx.zohomail.com
x.com       MX      mx2.zohomail.com
```

What can I do to handle email through zohomail's MX records and still keep my domain name mapped to herokuapp because that's where the app is running?

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Related: [Why does Heroku warn against “naked” domain names?](http://serverfault.com/q/408017/126632)

Comment: Is your DNS service actually *allowing* you to have a CNAME at the apex of your domain, or did you make a mistake while redacting this?

Answer (score 2):

A `CNAME` record defines that one *name* is an alias of another *name* (the canonical name).

The implication of having an entire name be an alias is that it cannot also have records of its own, meaning you cannot have those `MX` records.
This is also why you cannot have a `CNAME` record at the zone apex (where you will always need at least `SOA` and `NS` records).

You may have to contact the service provider for a solution that does not involve the use of `CNAME` records.

One possibility that you could set up on your own would be to use a DNS service with an alias functionality that can add the specific record types that you need (`A`/`AAAA` records?) to your zone and keep those up to date based on a provided name. See services like [Route53](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values.html#resource-record-sets-values-alias), [DNSimple](http://blog.dnsimple.com/2011/11/introducing-alias-record/), [DnsMadeEasy](http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/services/aname-records/) and probably many others that provide that kind of functionality.

Another possibility would be to have `A`/`AAAA` records that points to a web server that can do an HTTP redirect to a URL that does not involve this particular name (ie `example.com` -> `www.example.com`).