# OVH and HEROKU DNS redirections failing for root

Tags: domain-name-system, heroku, ovh

I currently have a domain at OVH (let's call it mysite.com) which is setup by OVH with a bunch of different CNAME for different subdomains like :

```
smtp.mysite.com   CNAME   mysite.com
imap.mysite.com   CNAME   mysite.com
ftp.mysite.com    CNAME   mysite.com
...
```

I have deleted all this and would like only `root` and `www` ro redirect to my Heroku application.

I have then added both domains to my heroku app and got following redirections by Heroku :

```
www.mysite.com  CNAME            www.mysite.com.herokudns.com
mysite.com      ALIAS or ANAME   mysite.com.herokudns.com
```

The first one works well. For the second I have deleted the `A` reference to OVH server IP and tried to populate a `CNAME` to `mysite.com.herokudns.com` as indicated (no `ANAME` or `ALIAS` types available at OVH though) . But OVH does not allow this (as per RFC also).

Is there a solution to have root name redirected to Heroku anyway ?

(currently root address redirects to OVH mailer application !!?? which I am not sure where it comes from  as all OVH `CNAME` and `A` types have been deleted. Seems it is picking up the `MX` record by default ...)

Comment: ALIAS and ANAME are [not real](https://serverfault.com/q/408017/126632) DNS records. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/apex-domains

Comment: Thanks Michael. I deleted my other comments as I misunderstood the whole thing. But it seems that root domain configuration is domain server dependent https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#configuring-dns-for-root-domains I have raised a ticket to OVH to know if they allowed this.

Comment: I don't think you can do that on OVH. But you can always point the naked domain A record at [wwwizer](http://wwwizer.com/) or something.

Comment: I do have SSL through Heroku (paid dyno) but will look into wwwizer. Other thing, I could load a simple HTML file through FTP at root and redirect to the www.mysite.com . Not sure if this is a clever tweak. Also I am eager to hear from OVH as so many domain name providers offer the Cname at root, why would they not either...