# Godaddy - How do I set a catchall CNAME?

Tags: domain-name-system, wildcard

I have Ape installed in /APE_Server. I'm configuring APE and the tutorial says:

1. Create a subdomain pointing to the server where APE is installed.
2. Create a Catch-All CNAME redirecting all requests from *.ape.yourdomain.com to ape.yourdomain.com

So basically I must create a subdomain that points to the root and a wildcard DNS?

I can do the first. For the second, I click ADD RECORD, select CNAME and it says:

```
Enter an Alias Name: 
Points to Host Name:
```

I tried to enter simply: *.ape and ape but it doesn't work. How do I do it?

Comment: I could point `*.ape` to `173.201.8.249` with type A record but I don't know if that is what I am supposed to do to get APE working. Anyone knows if this is equivalent to point 2 of the tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[An earlier question asked whether a wildcard CNAME record was a good idea or not](https://serverfault.com/questions/44618/is-a-wildcard-cname-dns-record-valid).  Answer mentioned that GoDaddy didn't support it even though it is technically fine.

I had the same issue. You can achieve what you need using an A record with `*` in the host field, and your server's IP address in the Points to Field. You can also set the host field of an A record to `*.somesubdomain`, if you only want wild-card subdomains of yet another subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

Try a '@' and/or try an Arecord.

Comment: I could do A from `*.ape` to `173.201.8.249` but I don't know if that is what I am supposed to do to get APE working. I don't know the difference between A and CNAME either. Will doing this work the same as doing what is asked by the tutorial?

Comment: A CNAME is a reference to an Arecord. Using an Arecord instead of a Cname is preferred, since when looking up a Cname the initial request returns the target Arecord, then a second request returns the Arecord.

Answer (score 0):

point *.ape to ape (CNAME) 
and
ape to 173.201.8.249 (A record)

Comment: that's what I did but the system doesn't consider *.ape valid