# Domain mapping via hostname instead of IP

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, cname-record, a-record

Is it possible to configure DNS such that:

1. anysubdomain.clientsite.com has CNAME record to abc.ourservice.com
2. abc.ourservice.com has A record to our dedicated IP (so that if we change servers in the future, our clients won't have to update their CNAME mappings)

We can then capture & process requests made to anysubdomain.clientsite.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly should be possible, the owner of `clientsite.com` should just setup a [wildcard record](https://serverfault.com/questions/44618/is-a-wildcard-cname-dns-record-valid).  Keep in mind that the DNS manager provided by some registrars doesn't support a wildard record, or a wildcard cname record.

```
* IN CNAME abc.ourservice.com.
```

Your shouldn't have to do anything special for your A record for `abc.ourservice.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you'd have to replace (or introduce to your clients) an intermediate CNAME to give you such flexibility. (In lieu of your A record)

So basically you'd have:

foo.client.com (CNAME) => intermediate.yourservice.com (CNAME) => actualnode.yourservice.com (A)

Then you can re-map your "intermediate CNAME" to whatever A record you'd like without notifying clients.