# Getting domain without www in front to point to same place as with www in front

Tags: domain, subdomain, godaddy

Consider the following screenshot from Godaddy:

[image]

Why am I not allowed to make the * refer to ghs.google.com, when I can make www point to that just below? I think there is something fundamental that I have misunderstood here, but this should really not be that difficult.

What I want to achieve is that open-org.com points to the same place as www.open-org.com. Preferably they should both point to open-org.com like serverfault.com.

There are some similar questions to this question around, but their solutions do not seem to work on Godaddy.

I am using Google Sites for web hosting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not `CNAME` the root of the domain - but you certainly may `CNAME` the `*` name, which you should be able to do in the `CNAME` section of that interface.  Note that this will ***not*** apply to the name `open-org.com` though.

A `CNAME` of the root violates the rules of DNS, since you have (and need) `SOA` and `NS` records on the root name for your domain to function properly.

Your best option is probably to have `open-org.com`'s `A` record point to a server which does an HTTP redirect to `www.open-org.com` - GoDaddy may provide this kind of redirection as a built-in service, not sure.

Comment: Thank you for providing me with the vocabulary to find this on Google. [This](http://help.godaddy.com/article/422) page explains how this is done on GoDaddy.

Answer (score 0):

It wants an IP address, not a name since it's [an A record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_record#A).

"[GoDaddy won't let you set up a wildcard in a CNAME record](https://serverfault.com/questions/44618/is-a-wildcard-cname-dns-record-valid#44635)."  As shane implies above.

But it's worth testing what the first comment on that post states:

"Just set the Host to "**"." – Chris Pietschmann